# Создание графиков Android

Tags: java, android

Приложение должно выводить результат в виде графиков. Хотя я уж думаю может красиво нарисованный прогресс бары использовать?

Я нашел не плохую на вид либру **MPAndroidChart**, но вот разобраться в ней толком не могу. Может где-то есть инструкция, статьи или какие-то аналоги с описанием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще есть много разных библиотек, но вы выбрали одну из самых популярных насколько я понял. Вот есть статья по вашему вопросу. Добавляем в активность код для заполнения графика:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
 
        BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDescription("My Chart");
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();
    }
 
    private ArrayList getDataSet() {
        ArrayList dataSets = null;
 
        ArrayList valueSet1 = new ArrayList();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);
 
        ArrayList valueSet2 = new ArrayList();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);
 
        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
 
        dataSets = new ArrayList();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }
 
    private ArrayList getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList xAxis = new ArrayList();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;
    }
}
```

и на выходе получаем график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот есть хороший туториал](https://javapapers.com/android/android-chart-example-app-using-mpandroidchart/) где показано как работать с этой библиотекой и показаны варианты графиков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же там можно зайти в репозиторий примера приложения, чтобы посмотреть полностью проект. [Вот тут](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40) можно найти и другие библиотеки по данной тематике.